# SVN problem - commit taking forever to fix incomplete prior commit

Tags: plugins, svn

See attached screenshot. Is this normal for an svn commit? I usually use github, and it goes much faster.

The major problem here is that I didn't realize my plugin uploaded to wordpress with only top directories (not the subdirectories included) hence its BROKEN. Its very frustrating, because I'm adding the sub-directories, and this commit issue here is happening.

In short, its not committing! Is it hanging? I see motion (the dots) yet I see no  evidence that this is normal...its not a huge plugin. Why is this taking so long? Am I locked out?

[image]

Comment: Please do **not** use words like *urgent* in your title. No one have to answer your question nor does anyone have to answer your question within a specific time frame. Everyone here are a member just like you, no one gets paid to to be here, we all offer up our own free time to help other users, and no one is obliged to answer any question whatsoever. If you post a good question with all relevant info and research, someone with knowlegde in the specific field will answer your question. Thank you :-)

Comment: Sorry you got offended. I'll avoid using emergency words in an emergency.